# How to mix inheritance strategies with JPA annotations and Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, jpa, annotations, hierarchy

According to the *Hibernate Reference Documentation* it should be possible to mix different inheritance mapping strategies when using Hibernate's XML-Metadata:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-mixing-tableperclass-tablepersubclass

However, the corresponding section of the *Hibernate Annotations Reference Guide* does not cover that:
`http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e1168`

On the other hand, the JavaDocs suggest that mixing inheritance strategies should be possible. For instance in javax.persistence.DiscriminatorColumn it says:

> The strategy and the discriminator column are only specified in the root of an entity class hierarchy **or subhierarchy in which a different inheritance strategy** is applied.

---

The following is an example for the mapping I'm trying to achieve. I'd like to use *table-per-subclass* mapping near the root of the hierarchy, but change to *table-per-class-hierarchy* mapping near the leaves. Here's some example code:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED )
public abstract class A implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    private String id;

    // other mapped properties...
}

@Entity
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE )
public class BB extends A
{
    // other mapped properties and associations...
}

@Entity
public class BB1 extends BB
{
    // other stuff, not necessarily mapped...
}

@Entity
public class BB2 extends BB
{
    // other stuff, not necessarily mapped...
}

@Entity
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE )
public class CC extends A
{
    // other mapped properties and associations...
}

@Entity
public class CC1 extends CC
{
    // other stuff, not necessarily mapped...
}

...
```

What I expect from this mapping is having exactly 3 tables: `A`, `BB`, and `CC`. Both `BB` and `CC` should have a default discriminator column called `DTYPE`. They should also provide all columns necessary for all mapped properties and associations of their respective subclasses.

Instead , the class hierarchy seems to use the *table-per-subclass* inheritance strategy throughout. I.e. I get an own table for each of the entities mentioned above. I'd like to avoid this, since the leaves of the class-hierarchy are extremely light-weight and it just seems overkill to have a separate table for each of them!

---

Did I overlook something? Any advice is highly appreciated! I'll be glad to provide additional info...

Comment: This is not working for me on Hibernate 3.6.3

Comment: @Meeque what if A was "TABLE_PER_CLASS" and u wanted same for class C (and the hierarchy below it) and wanted to have SINGLE_TABLE only for the hierarchy rooted at class BB ? In your solution below you have inverted the problem for the solution , do you think the variation i am mentioning can be addressed

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> According to the Hibernate Reference Documentation it should be possible to mix different inheritance mapping strategies when using Hibernate's XML-Metadata (...)

Actually, it's not *really* supported, they are "cheating" using a secondary table to switch from the single table strategy in the example of the documentation. Quoting *Java Persistence with Hibernate*:

> You can map whole inheritance
>   hierarchies by nesting
>   `<union-subclass>`, `<sub- class>`,
>   and `<joined-subclass>` mapping
>   elements. You can’t mix them — for
>   example, to switch from a
>   table-per-class hierarchy with a
>   discriminator to a normalized
>   table-per-subclass strategy. **Once
>   you’ve made a decision for an
>   inheritance strategy, you have to
>   stick to it**.
>
> This isn’t completely true, however.
>   With some Hibernate tricks, you can
>   switch the mapping strategy for a
>   particular subclass. For example, **you
>   can map a class hierarchy to a single
>   table, but for a particular subclass,
>   switch to a separate table with a
>   foreign key mapping strategy**, just as
>   with table per subclass. This is
>   possible with the `<join>` mapping
>   element:
>
> ```
> <hibernate-mapping>
>   <class name="BillingDetails"
>       table="BILLING_DETAILS">
>
>     <id>...</id>
>
>     <discriminator
>         column="BILLING_DETAILS_TYPE"
>         type="string"/>
>     ...
>     <subclass
>         name="CreditCard"
>         discriminator-value="CC">
>       <join table="CREDIT_CARD">
>         <key column="CREDIT_CARD_ID"/>
>
>         <property name="number" column="CC_NUMBER"/>
>         <property name="expMonth" column="CC_EXP_MONTH"/>
>         <property name="expYear" column="CC_EXP_YEAR"/>
>         ...
>       </join>
>     </subclass>
>
>     <subclass
>         name="BankAccount"
>         discriminator-value="BA">
>       <property name=account" column="BA_ACCOUNT"/>
>       ...
>     </subclass>
>   ...
>   </class>
> </hibernate-mapping>
> ```

And you could achieve the same with annotations:

> Java Persistence also supports this mixed inheritance mapping strategy with annotations. Map the superclass `BillingDetails` with `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE`, as you did before. Now map the subclass you want to break out of the single table to a secondary table.
>
> ```
> @Entity
> @DiscriminatorValue("CC")
> @SecondaryTable(
>     name = "CREDIT_CARD",
>     pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "CREDIT_CARD_ID")
> )
> public class CreditCard extends BillingDetails {
>     @Column(table = "CREDIT_CARD",
>         name = "CC_NUMBER",
>         nullable = false)
>     private String number;
>     ...
> }
> ```

I didn't test this but you could maybe try to:

- map A using a SINGLE_TABLE strategy
- map BB, CC, etc using the `@SecondaryTable` annotation.

I've not tested this, I don't know if it will work well for BB1, BB2.

#### Reference

- Java Persistence with Hibernate

  - 5.1.5 Mixing inheritance strategies (p207-p210)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Pascal. I have to say that the suggested approach seems quite verbose. In particular, I'll have to specify the desired table for each property I map in a subclass. Otherwise it will be mapped to a column of the single table for the hierarchy, right?
Well I'll give it a shot tomorrow, and I'll report back...

Comment: @Meeque Yes, it's verbose. But this is your only option so you don't really have the choice.

Comment: Well, this suggestion actually worked well:) However, it still does not feel natural, and there are a few disadvantages.

Comment: Thanks Pascal. Although this answer was 7 years ago, I tried this solution today with Hibernate 5.2.10.Final and it still worked.

Answer (score 31):

Just for the sake of clarity, here is Pascal's solution applied to the example code from my question:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE )
@DiscriminatorColumn( name = "entityType", 
        discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING )
public abstract class A implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    private String id;

    // other mapped properties...
}

@Entity
@SecondaryTable( name = "BB" )
public class BB extends A
{
    @Basic( optional = false)
    @Column( table = "BB" )
    private String property1;

    // other mapped properties and associations...
}

@Entity
public class BB1 extends BB
{
    // other stuff, not necessarily mapped...
}

@Entity
public class BB2 extends BB
{
    // other stuff, not necessarily mapped...
}

@Entity
@SecondaryTable( name = "CC" )
public class CC extends A
{
    @ManyToOne( optional = false)
    @JoinColumn( table = "CC" )
    private SomeEntity association1;

    // other mapped properties and associations...
}

@Entity
public class CC1 extends CC
{
    // other stuff, not necessarily mapped...
}

...
```

I've successfully applied this approach to my problem, and I'll stick to it for the time being. However I still see the following disadvantages:

- The discriminator column is located in the main table for the hierarchy, the table for root-enity `A`. In my case, it would be sufficient to have the discriminator column in the secondary tables `BB` and `CC`.
- Anytime one adds properties and associations to subclasses of `BB` or `CC`, he/she has to specify that they should be mapped to the respective secondary table. Would be nice, if there was a way to make that the default.

Comment: Thanks, this saved my life.  In our case, we also had `@Embeddables` in each of `BB` and `CC` from above, so we had to go in to the `@Embeddable` and set the table attribute for each `@Column` there to match the secondary table.  I suppose if we needed to have different tables for those `@Embeddables` from `BB` or `CC`, we would have needed to use `@AttributeOverrides`, but kinda lucked out on that bit.

Comment: *"Anytime one adds properties and associations to subclasses of BB or CC, he/she has to specify that they should be mapped to the respective secondary table"* How can I do this if I want to add a ManyToMany association to BB or CC?