# >>> Hibernate Example using inheritence <<<

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities, one is Item, another Fruit. I want to implement first as super class of the other, and I want all the parameters from the super class to be inherited by its subclass.

Also I want, when building database to bind that superclass table and all its properties to the subclass table, i.e., if I create more subclasses, I don't want for all of them to write values which were supposed to be in super class.

How should I achieve this?

item.java

```
  @MappedSuperclass
  @DiscriminatorColumn(name="Item")
  @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
  public abstract class Item implements java.io.Serializable
   {
      // here goes all values of the class Item
   }
```

fruit.java

```
   @Entity
   @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ART_ID")
   public class Fruit extends Item implements java.io.Serializable{
      // here goes proper values of this class 
   }
```

database.db

```
   create table Item
   (
    ITEM_ID          bigint not null auto_increment,
    ITEM_NAME         varchar(25) not null,
    );

   create table Fruit
    (
    FRUIT_DATEFROZEN date,
    );

);
```

Answer (score 1):

I implemented something like the following for a [complicated inheritance tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202816/hibernate-discriminator-column-with-table-per-subclass) I have.

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Item
{
    @Id
    Long id;

    String name;
}

@DiscriminatorValue("FRUIT")
@SecondaryTable( name = "fruit" )
public class NumberAnswer extends Item
{
    @Column(table = "fruit")
    Date frozen;
}

create table Item
(
  ID     bigint not null auto_increment,
  NAME   varchar(25) not null,
);

create table Fruit
(
  ID     bigint not null
  FROZEN date,
);
```

Comment: How should I then implement my db file?Should I have create table Item
   (ITEM_ID          bigint not null auto_increment,
    ITEM_NAME         varchar(25) not null,
    );
create table Fruit
    (
    FRUIT_DATEFROZEN date,
    );or for each subclasses table I should have values of the superclass table like  
create table Fruit
    (ITEM_ID          bigint not null auto_increment,
    ITEM_NAME         varchar(25) not null,
    FRUIT_DF date,
    );create table Meat
    (ITEM_ID          bigint not null auto_increment,
    ITEM_NAME         varchar(25) not null,
    MEAT varchar(25),
    );

Comment: In the subclass tables, the ids do not increment since they will be the same id as the main table and you should probably add a foreign key from fruit.id => item.id

Comment: I see! So I will have to make fruit_id which is foreign key to item_id! Great, just as I wanted, now will see if it works. :)