# JPA Mixed Inheritance Strategy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have 3 entities:

```
@Entity
public abstract class A {
  @Id
  public Long id;
  public String a1;
  public String a2;
  public String a3;

  //much more fields    
  //getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class B extends A {
  public String b1;
  public String b2;
  public String b3;

  //much more fields
  //getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class C extends A {
  public String c;
  //that's it. no more data

  //getters and setters
}
```

I want to map these classes to 2 tables. First one will contain all of `A` and `C` data (i.e. `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance). And the second one will contain `B`'s data and a foreign key to `A` (i.e. `JOINED` inheritance).

I tried the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915026/how-to-mix-inheritance-strategies-with-jpa-annotations-and-hibernate), but it doesn't work for me. The attributes of `BB1` and `BB2` are also included into `A`.

How to implement such a strategy? Classes `A` and `C` are as different as Dog and Cat are, so I can't merge them into one class.

Also I don't want to use table-per-hierarchy which would result in duplicating lots of `A`'s data.

Comment: im not clear why you want to use a join strategy...the recommended way in the hibernate docs is to use table-per-class hierarchy with a discriminator -- will make your life simpler.  perhaps put some details into those classes to help us understand?

Comment: @hvgotcodes Using TABLE_PER_CLASS strategy will lead to unnormalized data. Also, the inheritance tree could be quite large, so it would hurt performance as well.

Comment: the tradeoff might be worth the unnormalized data.  How large could the inheritance tree be, and how different are the classes in the hierarchy?

Comment: @hvgotcodes The inheritance tree could be about 5 levels deep. The thing here is that class `A` contains a lot of fields, so is the class `B`, but `C` has just one. So it looks really redundant to copy all fields of `A` twice. Our DBA definitely won't approve it.

Comment: i said table per class *hierarchy*, not table per concrete subclass.  one table for all the classes.

Comment: In my opinion you should try to convince your DBA that a consistent data model is more important than a small performance boost. If you already have a inheritance depth of 5 using the JOINED strategy then I would also use JOINED for C.

Comment: @JörnHorstmann Thanks for sharing your thoughts. I think so too, but sometimes it's not us who decide. The inheritance tree turned up being not so deep, and the top class is using SINGLE_TABLE hierarchy, however I used the trick which I described in my own answer to switch to another table. I've lost the benefits of inheritance but made it work eventually.

Comment: Hibernate used to allow mixing inheritance, but I don´t know how to do it using pure JPA. Look here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-mixing-tableperclass-tablepersubclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending so much time on this, and not getting any answer, I've come to this solution (which could be not the best):

```
@Entity
public abstract class A implements Serializable {
  @Id
  public Long id;

  public String a1;
  public String a2;
  public String a3;

  //much more fields    
  //getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class B implements Serializable {

  @Id  
  @Column(name="id", nullable=false)  
  public Long id;

  @MapsId  
  @OneToOne(optional=false)  
  @JoinColumn(name="id")  
  public A a;

  public String b1;  
  public String b2;  
  public String b3;

  //much more fields
  //getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class C extends A {  

  public String c;
  //that's it. no more data

  //getters and setters
}
```

**Conclusion**
I was amazed at how such well-supported and popular technology as JPA does not offer a solution for such a trivial case. As pointed out by Pascal Thivent in his answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915026/how-to-mix-inheritance-strategies-with-jpa-annotations-and-hibernate) question, *Hibernate* is cheating us, using a `secondary table`, which is a very tedious and error-prone approach (you should manually specify for each field, to which table it belongs). So it looks like, there is still a room for improvement in **JPA** spec.

Comment: Current JPA spec (paragraph 2.1.10) is saying that `Support for the combination of inheritance strategies within a single entity inheritance hierarchy is not required by this specification.` Keeping that in mind, in similar cases I use JOINED strategy for all of my entities.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Will hope that in the next version of spec, this feature will be mandatory.

Comment: Btw, not sure which version of specification you read, but I just took a look at final JPA 2.0 specification for evaluation [here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) and it seems that the sentence that you mentioned is in the paragraph 2.12.

Comment: You have 7 hours left to write this in separate answer and I will accept it, and award a bounty, which will be lost otherwise :)

Comment: Done :) Link to JPA spec included.

Comment: The spec you pointed to is kind of old (now EJB version is **3.1** and **JPA 2.0** was a separate JSR with specification located [here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/). And the paragraph is 2.12. However I'll award your answer, just please correct it with more up-to-date information.

Answer (score 6):

[JPA spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/)  (paragraph 2.12) is saying that `Support for the combination of inheritance strategies within a single entity inheritance hierarchy is not required by this specification`. 
Keeping that in mind, in similar cases I usually use JOINED strategy for all of my entities.