# Hibernate annotations and mixing Inheritance types

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, annotations

I'm working with hibernate and annotations and I'm facing issues annotating my class hierarchy.
My class hierarchy is the following:

**ClassA** is abstract
**ClassB** is abstract and extends **ClassA**
**ClassC** extends **ClassB**

Only **ClassC** can be instantiated and I would like to have:

- fields from **ClassA** and **ClassB** in the same table ClassB
- fields from **ClassC** (not those of **ClassA** and **ClassB**) in another table ClassC

The foreign Key in **ClassC** pointing to **ClassB** is in column `id` of ClassC

Here the code I wrote:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class ClassA  

@Entity
@Table(name = "classB", catalog = "test")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class ClassB extends ClassA

@Entity
@Table(name = "classC", catalog = "test")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class ClassC extends ClassB
```

With this I have the following error messages :

```
Mixing inheritance strategy in a entity hierarchy is not allowed, ignoring sub strategy in: ClassB
```

And

```
Root entity should not hold an PrimaryKeyJoinColum(s), will be ignored
```

I've read several posts mentioning that multiple inheritance types can't be mixed, some other trying to give warkarounds for some special cases but I didn't findout how to achieve what I would like to have... which is a quite common case I guess.
Is there a nice solution for that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915026/how-to-mix-inheritance-strategies-with-jpa-annotations-and-hibernate

Comment: I've read this post before, and it is not definitly not answering my question. I really need to have these 3 levels: ClassA definied with TABLE_PER_CLASS startegy and ClassB extending ClassA with JOINED startegy. The mentioned post is not taking this case into account :/