# Inheritence Strategy when some entities do not have any specific columns or table

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa-2.0

In database we have a "parent" table with a discriminator column, and depending on this discriminator column some columns are stored in specific tables or some relationships (many/one-to-many) are allowed.

In our mapping we wanted to implement it like

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class A {
    @Id
    @Column
    private int id;
}

@Entity
public class B extends A {
    @Column
    private String specificField;
}

@Entity
public class C extends A {
    @OneToMany
    private List<OtherEntity> otherEntities;
}
```

Unfortunately Hibernate wants to join on table C, which does not exist since it would only contain the FK to A. Is there a way to keep this strategy but tell that no join is necessary?

Otherwise, what is the cleanest solution? Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915026/how-to-mix-inheritance-strategies-with-jpa-annotations-and-hibernate) I thought using the `SINGLE_TABLE` strategy with the `@SecondaryTable` annotation on child entities that require it but it seems heavier to configure (having to declare, for each column, the source table).