# How to return multiple classes extending class from repository?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I would like to receive all of the records, which extend from my abstract class. I have the following:

**Product.java**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="descriminatorColumn")
@Table(name="ProductCatalog")
public abstract class Product {
    @Id
    private Long id;
}
```

**PC.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PC")
public class PC extends Product{
    private String pcType;
}
```

**TV.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TV")
public class TV extends Product{
    private String tvType;
}
```

And **ProductRepository.java**

```
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Long> {
    <T extends Product>List<T> findAll(); // not working
}
```

In my controller I have:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/product", method = GET)
public <T extends Product>List<T> findProducts(){
    return productRepository.findAll();
}
```

How can I make the `findAll()` return all of the items from the subclasses that extend class `Product`?

**UPDATE:**

I have added the following method to the **ProductRepository**:

```
<T extends Product>List<T> findProducts();
```

and changed it in the controller - is this the proper way to do it ?

The error that I've using this is:

```
 Caused by:
 org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
 property findProducts found for type Product!
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it the following way in my repository. Is a generic answer so you could use it for any class, even your abstract class:

```
public <T> List<T> findAll(Class<T> type) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> criteria = builder.createQuery(type);
    Root<T> root = criteria.from(type);     
    CriteriaQuery<T> all = criteria.select(root);
    TypedQuery<T> allQuery = entityManager.createQuery(all);

    return (List<T>) allQuery.getResultList();
}
```

Edit: False remark removed.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I over read that. But shouldn't you then use the `@SecondaryTable` annotation? Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/3915026/6505091