# Hibernate, JPA, joined table inheritance when not all subtypes have their own table results in circular dependency error

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, jpa

I'm trying to use JPA with Hibernate to read data from an *existing* schema. I cannot modify the schema. There is a User class with multiple subclasses. Some of these subclasses have additional data that is stored in joined tables, and some don't. As a concrete example, consider the following 3 classes and 2 tables. (In reality, there are a couple dozen variants and about a dozen tables.)

- `User` is the common base class. It includes a discriminator column named userType. The table `USER` holds the data common to all `User` classes, including a numeric `USERID` value.
- `StandardUser` is one variant with no additional data.
- `LoginUser` is another variant that has a username and password, stored in a table `LOGIN_USER` that is joined to `USER` on `USERID`.

The following works with OpenJPA:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="USERTYPEID", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public class User {
    private @Id long userId;
    private String userName;
    private int userTypeId;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class StandardUser extends User {

}

@Entity
@Table(name="LOGIN_USER")
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class LoginUser extends User {
    private String login;
    private String password;
    ....
}
```

It generates SQL code that joins `USER` and `LOGIN_USER` (with a left outer join) on `USERID`, and properly creates a StandardUser or a LoginUser depending on whether the userTypeId value is 1 or 2.

When I link the same code with Hibernate instead of OpenJPA, I get the error message

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Foreign key circularity dependency involving the following tables:
```

There are no tables listed in the error message. I set a breakpoint on the exception, and it is trying to resolve the "dependency" between "USER" and "USER", or so it appears. I have tried this with Hibernate versions 3.6 and 4.1.7.

(Why not stick with OpenJPA? I am having a separate problem there, relating to load time code rewriting conflicts with JAXB.)

Answer (score 1):

I should have spent more time looking at the related questions. It appears that the strategy proposed in [Changing the inheritance strategy in branches of the class hierarchy via JPA annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825676/changing-the-inheritance-strategy-in-branches-of-the-class-hierarchy-via-jpa-ann) will do what I need.

Specifically, if I change the code to read as follows, it compiles and runs and passes my unit tests.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="USERTYPEID", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class User {
    private @Id long userId;
    private String userName;
    private int userTypeId;
    ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class StandardUser {
}

@Entity
@SecondaryTable(name="LOGIN_USER")
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class LoginUser extends User {
    @Column(table="LOGIN_USER")
    private String login;
    @Column(table="LOGIN_USER")
    private String password;
    ....
}
```

Comment: Does this still work for you? I have a similar problem and in my case I get the equivalent of:
`javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [standard_user]`